# Keycloak authentication

Tags: keycloak

I have a question regarding Keycloak and obtaining an Access Token.

I have two separate applications set up as 2 different clients in keycloak.
Both are using the same LDAP (Active directory) server for authentication which is set up in keycloak as user federation.

A user is logged into applicationA using the keycloak login page.
Now the user wants to open applicationB on click of a button on its webpage.

On click of the button applicationA should be able to retrieve 
an access token from keycloak and use it to launch applicationB.

But it should not be asked to login into keycloak again.

Once it receives the token it should be able to launch applicationB using the token. ApplicationB should check the validity of the token passed
and retrieves the user details from the keycloak server.

What is the way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

In this case, why do you need 2 clients for two applications? You can pass the same token generated when application A is logged in and validate it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your precise settings, so I cannot really clear this without further info, but have you tried going to `Authentication -> Flows -> Browser and disable cookies`.

Answer (score 0):

You must decide which types of application would be ApplicationA (AA) and ApplicationB (AB). In OIDC all application could be divided in two types:

1. Application that can obtain token from keycloak (via standard, implicit or direct_grant flows).
2. Applications that obtain token from incoming requests (usually that is a pure backend, 'bearer-only' in Keycloak terminology). As example they can extract AccessToken from Authorization header with bearer scheme `Authorization: Bearer {jwt_access_token}`

So in your case i guess that AA should be an application of type 1 and AB should be bearer-only (type 2), so there should be 2 client settings in keycloak. Typical flow would be:

1. List item
2. User opens AA
3. AA redirects user to Keycloak
4. User log in keycloak (now he hast keycloak sso cookies in his browser)
5. Keycloak redirects user to AA (with set of query params like `code=..`)
6. AA uses `code` value from redirect request and exchange it to the token pair via **backchannel** request to Keycloak
7. AA now can perform request to AB with access token in Authorization header (Note that AB doesn't need to do any additional request to Keycloak for checking token validity)
8. Note that it's AA responsibility to refresh token pairs periofically

Also check out Admin Console application (trace request via browser developer console). Thats actually two OIDC clients: Admin UI is a first type application and backend as second type application (bearer-only)